# Conditional expectation for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Assume $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, $\mathbf{X}\sim N_3 (\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)\neq 0$, for $i\neq j$. What is $\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2|a_1X_1+a_2X_2+a_3 X_3>t]$ for any arbitrary number $a_i,t\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I don't think this will have an exact form

Comment: I could calculate the exact solution for bivariate case, $E[X_1 X_2 | X_1+X_2 >t]$. Any good approximation will also work for me!